# How can I cancel backgroundWorker in specific case and start the backgroundWorker over?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 top:

```
ExtractImages ei = new ExtractImages();
```

In form1 constructor i start the backgroundworker first time

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In dowork event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
       return; // this will fall to the finally and close everything    
    }
    else
    {              
       ei.ProgressChanged += (senders, eee) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(eee.Percentage, eee.StateText);
       ei.Init();
    }
}
```

In progresschanged

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label7.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
    label8.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
}
```

In completed

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null) { ProgressBar1.Value = 100; }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

In the class top

```
public bool WebProblem = false;

public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
    public string StateText { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

public void Init()
{
    object obj = null;
    int index = 0;
    ExtractCountires();
    foreach (string cc in countriescodes)
    {
        // raise event here
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(obj, new ProgressEventArgs { Percentage = 100 * index / countriescodes.Count, StateText = cc });
        ExtractDateAndTime("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + cc);
        index += 1;
    }
    ImagesLinks();
}
```

Method in class

```
public void ExtractDateAndTime(string baseAddress)
{
     try
     {
         var wc = new WebClient();
         wc.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
         HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

         var temp = wc.DownloadData("/en");
         doc.Load(new MemoryStream(temp));

         var secTokenScript = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
         .Where(e =>
              String.Compare(e.Name, "script", true) == 0 &&
                   String.Compare(e.ParentNode.Name, "div", true) == 0 &&
                         e.InnerText.Length > 0 &&
                             e.InnerText.Trim().StartsWith("var region")
                                 ).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
         var securityToken = secTokenScript;
         securityToken = securityToken.Substring(0, securityToken.IndexOf("arrayImageTimes.push"));
         securityToken = secTokenScript.Substring(securityToken.Length).Replace("arrayImageTimes.push('", "").Replace("')", "");
         var dates = securityToken.Trim().Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
         var scriptDates = dates.Select(x => new ScriptDate { DateString = x });
         foreach (var date in scriptDates)
         {
            DatesAndTimes.Add(date.DateString);
         }
     }
     catch(WebException wex)
     {
         WebProblem = true;
     }
}
```

What i want to do is once the WebProblem is true stop the loop in the Init() and stop/cancel the backgroundworker in form1.

Then in the backgroundworker completed event throw a message to a label about the problem. And start a timer and after 30 seconds start the backgroundworker again.

If the exception happen and i will use a break point in the catch and click continue it will continue but i want that once there was a problem stop everything and start over again until it will pass without any problem in the middle.

Comment: It does not make any sense to connect your `ProgressChanged` event handler from inside `DoWork` handler. Both must be set from the UI thread.

Comment: OK... I see. You have 2 levels of events. If you want to restart, then in Completed handler, you check if you need to restart... What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of really peculiar stuff there. I suggest starting with a [BackgroundWorker tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners). Suggestions about what you have posted:

The form constructor is a really bad place to call `.RunWorkerAsync`; especially if you want to be able to restart the background process again. If you really want to start your BackgroundWorker immediately, you should call something like this in your Form_Load method:

```
 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(new Uri("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx"));
```

Your `DoWorkEventHandler` is where you should do your background work, check for cancellation, and report results and you aren't doing any of those. You want something like:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var result = new List<DateString>();
    var baseUri = (Uri)e.Argument;
    var countryCodes = ExtractCountries();
    foreach (var cc in countryCodes)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
           e.Cancel = true;
           return;
        }

        result.Add(ExtractDateAndTime(new Uri(baseUri, "?region=" + cc));
    }

    e.Result = result;
}
```

You want `ExtractCountries` to return an `IEnumerable` of whatever data you want to enumaerate, and `ExtractDateAndTime` to accept a complete `Uri` and return a list of the results. Do not embed that logic in the methods or use globals to return the results; everything you need is already a part of `BackgroundWorker`, do not create a new class just to hand off the data. Your `ExtractDateAndTime` declaration should look like this:

```
private DateString ExtractDateAndTime(Uri source)
```

Do **not** catch exceptions in `ExtractDateAndTime`; doing that will discard the exception and continue as if nothing was wrong, then return the wrong answer without warning. If you want to display the exception, let it propagate to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and inspect `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error`.

If you want to restart the `BackgroundWorker` if you get an error you want to declare a `Form.Timer` in your Design view or Form constructor and a `Tick` EventHandler something like:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(new Uri("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx"));
}
```

In your `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` do something like:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        AlertUserSomehow(e.Error);
        timer1.Interval = 30000;
        timer1.Start();
        return;
    }

    DoSomethingWith((List<DateString>)e.Result);
}
```